# Will the bad grade in a proposed studied subject be a red flag in my application?

Tags: application

I am currently doing final year project on a subject which I did not have a very good grade(I took three courses in this subject with grade A-, A and B+, only top 5-10% can earn a grade of A and A+). I am quite interested in it and plan to continue in this subject in graduate school. Will this grade have bad effect for my application? Can I indicate my interest clearly in my PS given that my grade is not perfect?

Comment: They are fantastic grades - what have the admissions people said?

Comment: By the way, the B+ is actually the grade for the graduate course. That is why I am so worried. Said...

Comment: @UV-D Thanks for UV-D's reply. Actually I have not consult the administrative people about this question (Actually I doubt that I could ask such questions to them?). As I am preparing for my PS, and I read in one post said a bad score in the interested subject is a "red flag". I am quite worried about this. UV-D, do you mean that I could still indicate my interest in my PS? Thanks!

Comment: @Daniel: _"A bad score in the interested subject is a 'red flag.'"_ This is true. But a bad score is well below a B+, particularly if only 5% of students get an A or A+!

Comment: @aeismail: Thank you for pointing that out clearly. This brings me another question. We all knew that grading system varies from department to department. For certain application form, I could indicate it clearly as the space is provided; for others, shall I state it clearly in my PS? Thanks

Comment: This may be handled with your university transcript, in which case further explanation isn't necessary, unless there are exceptional circumstances about which you want to make the committee aware. (For instance, serious illness, family emergency, etc.)

Answer (score 5):

I don't believe there is a serious stigma associated with an undergraduate getting a B+ in a graduate-level course. It is generally understood that undergraduates taking true graduate-level work (with graduate-level course numbers, etc.) are taking exceptionally advanced subjects, relative to their own preparation. Therefore, it is entirely understandable that you might have an A-, B+, or even a B in a graduate-level subject without it having a strong impact on your chances for graduate-school admissions. Exceptionally weak performance (corresponding to "failing" grades—usually C+ or lower) would be an exception to this, but I see no reason here why you should worry too much.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. I found it is hard to decide what to put in my PS. Maybe I will write a new post on this issue later. Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

One solution to this would be to ask the instructor of the course to write one of your letters of recommendation. If you were indeed performing at a graduate-level while still an undergrad, then he or she should note this in his/her letter.